# Почему "студеный" пишется с одним н? Корень -студ-, суффикс -ен- в прилагательных вроде как с двумя н пишется

Tags: орфография

Почему "студеный" пишется с одним н? Корень -студ-, суффикс -ен- в прилагательных вроде как с двумя н пишется.

Answer (score 3):

Студить - студеный, отглагольное прилагательное образовано от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида, в этом случае оно обозначает качественный признак (холодный), а не признак по действию.

Comment: А "студеный" не от "стужа" образовано?

Comment: Стужа - очень холодная, студёная погода, то есть семантически "стужа" определяется через "студёный". Словообразование: студить - студёный (прил.)/стуженный (прич.) - стужа. Сравнить: огонь - огненный, ОТЫМЕННЫЙ суффикс ЕНН

Answer (score 0):

Слово "студёный" образовано от глагола несовершенного вида (что делать? - студить). А если отглагольное прилагательное образовано от глагола несовершенного вида, оно пишется с одной Н.